# Is there a way to permanently change the value of a variable while debugging so it is not overridden in subsequent calls?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, plugins

In Eclipse / IntelliJ I see the option of "set value" but when we set the value of the variable, it gets overridden again if that call happens again.
Is there a way to permanently change the value of a variable while debugging, for all occurrences, without changing the source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a non-suspending breakpoint and, via the *Evaluate and log* option, make it assign a value to any variable or field in scope (as long as it's not `final`). Like this:

[image]

Just set it right after the variable is first initialized, or right before it's read. Every time the breakpoint is hit, it won't stop the execution of your program, but it will still evaluate the expression and change the value of the variable.